# Есть ли в предложениях речевые ошибки?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, уважаемые форумчане, есть ли в данных предложениях речевые ошибки:

> Орден Василию Тёркину не нужен... "он
> согласен на медаль", но только после
> войны.

Уч-ца зачеркнула "но только" и подписала сверху "да и то".

Ещё одно предложение:

> Василий  Тёркин обладает не только
> личными чертами характера, но ему
> присущи черты, которые были у всех
> русских воинов: мужество, смелость,
> патриотизм.

Слово "личные" она посчитала речевой ошибкой. А вторую часть переделала, и вот что вышло: *Василий Тёркин обладает не только чертами характера, но и присущими всем русским воинам: мужество, смелость, патриотизм.*

Еще хотелось бы узнать от специалистов, можно ли сказать, что Тёркин переплыл "ледяную реку"? Или это тоже речевая ошибка?

И последнее предложение:

> Автор называет его "герой-героем".

"Герой-героем" взято из текста, но учитель это тоже посчитала речевой ошибкой.

Comment: @Dima, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Дима, а Вам не кажется, что Вы излишне подвергаете сомнению компетентность Вашего учителя? (Вы, случайно, не на индивидуальном обучении?)

Она поставила все эти случаи именно как речевые ошибки (обозначила на полях значком "Р" и снизила за речь оценку) или просто подчеркнула? Попытаюсь объяснить, что она хотела сказать (может, не сумела по неопытности, может, Вы не захотели понять).

```
 Орден Василию Тёркину не нужен... "он согласен на медаль", но только после войны.
 Уч-ца зачеркнула "но только" и подписала сверху "да и то".
```

Надеюсь, только исправила, а ошибку не поставила? Это не речевая ошибка, а наивное понимание текста. Присоединительный оборот с "да и то" более уместен, потому что речь идёт о том, что он, как и все, воюет не ради наград:

Смертный бой не ради славы,

Ради жизни на земле.

*Но юность берёт своё, он не прочь "пощеголять" в наградах перед девчатами:*

Так скажу: зачем мне орден?

Я согласен на медаль.

На медаль. И то не к спеху.

Вот закончили б войну,

Вот бы в отпуск я приехал

На родную сторону.

*Заметили у автора "и то не к спеху"?* Вот поэтому учитель и подправила, сгладила, поставила Вам этот акцент мальчишеских мечтаний, а у Вас получилось, что он отказывается от ордена, а вот медаль ему подай, но не сейчас.

```
   Василий Тёркин обладает не только личными чертами характера, но ему присущи черты, которые были у всех русских воинов: мужество, смелость, патриотизм.
```

Личные черты характера - это действительно речевая ошибка, потому что, кроме личных, других не бывает. Обычно говорят "личные качества и черты характера человека". Говорят ещё "ЛИЧНОСТНЫЕ черты характера", но не личные. Здесь же ещё и грамматическая ошибка: союз не только, но и - двойной, а у Вас "не только, но ему присущи". Однородные члены не закончены, пошло новое предложение. Можно было сказать: "Мы видим не только яркую индивидуальность Тёркина, но и черты характера, свойственные целому поколению защитников Отечества, - мужество, стойкость и верность долгу".

```
переплыл ледяную реку
```

Ошибки нет, тем более речевой, река и впрямь ледяная:

```
  И, у заберегов корку

     Ледяную обломав,
```

Выражение "герой-героем", видимо, не понравилось чисто внешне, потому что по правилам такое сочетание пишется не через дефис, а раздельно:

http://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=defis_v_narechiax

Пишутся раздельно  сочетания двух одинаковых существительных в
усилительном значении, из которых одно стоит в именительном падеже,
а другое – в творительном:  честь честью, чудак чудаком, дело делом.

У Твардовского через дефис - авторское написание, учитель просто этого не помнит, это в главе "На привале".

Так что у Вас 1 речевая ошибка, одна грамматическая, одна неточность в содержании.

Comment: А сама фраза "автор называет его "герой-героем" мне тоже не нравится. Он не "называет", он даёт характеристику. Может, это она и имела в виду?

Comment: Я писал,что она не смогла  найти эту фразу в тексте.

Comment: Прискорбно, что учитель плохо ориентируется в тексте. Мне нравится Ваша въедливость, дотошность, стремление дойти где своим умом, где с помощью. А на учителя не держите зла,видимо, она неопытна или неспециалист. Я знаю, что иногда индивидуальные занятия дают неспециалистам, например, учителю начальных классов дают географию, русский язык и ещё что-нибудь.(Это связано с оплатой, с часами, не каждый соглашается)Попросите в 9 классе более опытного специалиста.

Answer (score 0):

1) "он согласен на медаль", но только после войны". Здесь лучше сделать замену, частица ТОЛЬКО  задает жесткое ограничение, ненужное здесь.

2) Я бы переделала так: "Василий Тёркин обладает не только особенными, личными чертами характера, но ему присущи качества, которые были у всех русских содлат:

3) Ледяная река - это метафора, перенос: холодная вода, ледяная вода, ледяная река.

Примеры

Рука болела, и кровь текла, а вокруг ничего не изменилось: заснеженные холмы, ЛЕДЯНАЯ река, тот берег в белесом тумане.

Нельзя даже сказать, что они отличаются большею безличностью. Впрочем, у них есть ЛИЧНЫЕ черты. (Ю. Н. Тынянов).

Я не сержусь, что сердятся и отворачиваются те, которые отыскивают в моих оригиналах свои СОБСТВЕННЫЕ черты и бранят меня (Н. В. Гоголь).

Comment: Спасибо.Но учитель не допускает такое выражение"личные" черты характера.Получается личных черт характера не бывает вообще.А словосочетание "ледяная река"есть и в большой школьной энциклопедии,в статье,где говорится о поэме"Василий Тёркин":..."рассказ о том ,как Тёркин переплыл ледяную реку"

Comment: А что ваш учитель может сказать об известных писателях, которые употребляли выражение "личные черты"? Это ошибка, стилистическая небрежность? И как он может доказать, что это сочетание неверно?

Comment: "Личные черты характера" - выражение, само по себе избыточное (достаточно "черты характера" или "личные черты"), но при противопоставлении "общим чертам" в нём нет тавтологии, которую, возможно, усматривает учитель - есть только стилистические недостатки.

Comment: А личные черты - это черты лица? "Темнота не допустила видеть мне черты лица его". Или: "Почти каждый день бон открывал в ней новые, милые черты ангельской души ее". Или вот еще: "Его цель ― помочь психологу оценить личностную динамику ребенка, а также его личностные черты во взаимосвязи".

Comment: Я спрошу у неё в следующий раз.Но думаю ,что она подразумевает"черты лица".У меня всего 10 часов в неделю  на все предметы и почти не  даётся времени  на развитие речи,поэтому большое спасибо всем вам за эту помощь!

Comment: Да нет, Дима, это, конечно, не черты лица, я к тому говорю, что выражение  "черты" не обязательно относятся только к характеру, а выражение "личные черты" не всегда ясно по смыслу.

Answer (score 0):

1) В первой фразе исправление по делу: в исходном варианте кажется, будто Тёркин выбирает меньшее из зол, т.е. согласен на медаль, но с условием, что только после войны.

2) Вторую фразу можно улучшить, но иначе (нельзя сказать "обладает не только чертами характера"). "Личными чертами характера" обладает любой человек, поэтому смысловая нагрузка такого выражения минимальна (здесь она лишь подводит к утверждению о собирательности образа). Но можно совместить имеющееся "не только" с упоминанием о "яркой индивидуальности" персонажа.

Василий Тёркин не только наделён (автором) яркой индивидуальностью, а ему присущи и черты характера всех русских воинов: мужество, смелость, патриотизм.

3) "Ледяная река" может восприниматься буквально замёрзшей, хотя есть устойчивое сочетание "ледяная вода". Лучше сказать: "переплыл замерзающую реку", "плыл в холодной, ледяной воде".

4) "Герой-героем" автором сказано о внешним впечатлении (выглядит героем, хоть и мал ростом). Поэтому у учительницы мог возникнуть вопрос, с какой целью эта фраза акцентирует данный эпитет - как она связана у вас с остальным текстом.

Comment: Не высок, не то чтоб мал,
Но герой - героем.
На Карельском воевал...
"Герой-героем" уч-ца  почему-то не нашла в тексте,её просто смутило такое сочетание.Я дальше в работе пояснил,почему автор так называет Тёркина.

Answer (score 0):

В первом предложении учительница исправила верно. Поскольку здесь не условие. Да и то - союз. Употребляется при присоединении члена предложения или части предложения (которые уточняют или ограничивают то, что утверждается), соответствуя по значению сл.: и то.

У каждого человека формируются и проявляются в ходе жизни и деятельности личные, индивидуальные черты характера, влияющие на его волевые, эмоциональные и интеллектуальные качества.Но, как отметил Александр, ''она лишь подводит к утверждению о собирательности образа''. А об отдельном конкретном человеке такое словосочетание некорректно.

У учительницы второе предложение получилось вообще безграмотным.***но и присущими всем русским воинам:*** далее никакой согласованности.

Ледяная река - это не только замерзшая река, но и холодная. Учительнице стоит заглянуть в словарь!

[image]

Comment: Я данным  словосочетанием "личные черты" хотел сказать, что  не все воины были балагурами, но все они были мужественными, смелыми людьми. Извиняюсь за повторы.

Comment: Дима, Александр дал прекрасный пример: ''...а ему присущи и черты характера всех русских воинов: мужество, смелость, патриотизм''.

Comment: Александр специалист,а я простой ученик 8 кл.

Comment: Поэтому и советую исправить ваш пример на приведенный Александром. Т.к. учительница тоже неправильно исправила.

Comment: Спасибо,вам большое!